# Can copper pipe support minor bends and creases?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing

I have a male threaded adapter for steel pipe on a 3/4" copper pipe. When twisting an extension steel pipe on the fitting, I applied a bit too much force and that slightly bent and creased the copper pipe, which I mostly reverted with channel locks.

I tested it and there was no leaks but the crease is still visible if you look hard. I was wondering if this compromises the pipe to be more succeptible to leaking in the future.

Comment: How do you feel about lying awake night after night listening for a drip drip drip?

Comment: There is no dripping right now and my question is about the probability of it happening in the future

Comment: I don't mean listening to the drip -- I mean waiting for the drip.

Comment: I can also wait for an asteroid to hit

Answer (score 2):

copper is fairly soft stuff and a single crease-uncrease operation won't cause a leak by itself. but that piece is now weaker than the rest of the pipe so it may  be the first part to fail is the system is over-stressed.

Comment: Agree.  Copper is generally rated for 20-50 years.  Creases will be reflected in the smoothness of the inside wall of the pipe and cause additional turbulence which will cause that inner wall to wear away.